# Issue to upload a file into folder flask app after deployment

Tags: python

I am using Flask to upload image file into folder. Using this code in app.py

APP.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.basename('/Desktop/hello_flask/uploads')

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/')

def hello_world():

   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])

  def upload_file():

     file = request.files['image']

     f = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename)

     file.save(f)

return render_template('index.html')
```

I created uploads folder within the project folder.

I tried removing `os.path.basename` and tried, even it is not working. Tried changing the directory address also. Everything is working fine in local IDE as visual studio, but is not working after deploying in AWS.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is happening when you attempt to upload the file on AWS? Is there a reason that you need the file uploaded next to the app? Are you uploading the document to your EC2 (or whatever you're using) instance, or to a mounted s3fs bucket?

I'm guessing that this path you are using `'/Desktop/hello_flask/uploads'` doesn't actually exist on your AWS instance. You should use an upload directory relative to where your app sits.

Comment: @AKHIL you  shoudl first check 2 things , first is the name attribute of the input tag is `name=image` and whether this script has the permissions required to access the path you choose.

Comment: UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Comment: This is what I changed the directory, even then I am not able to upload on EC2 instance.

Comment: Iam not uploading to EC2 instance, I just need to add it to specific folder present in my project.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.